# Shopify Subdomain Based Separate Stores

Tags: shopify

I want to implement 3 Shopify stores(Content is the same currency will be different). As

```
mywebsite.com- Global
uk.mywebsite.com-UK
us.mywebsite.com-US
```

I want to manage all 3 sites from the same Shopify admin panel instead of creating 3 separate. Is it possible with Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Shopify is unable to manage several Shopify stores together. The reasoning for this is because it ensures that orders/reports/shipping and a variety of other aspects don't get mixed in together. Ultimately, it could be quite a disaster, so it's best to keep store admins separate.

**Source :https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/Multiple-Shopify-Stores/td-p/367428**

Comment: Use multilanguage and multi-currency options to create the store.